# JSON data on TableView using SwiftyJSON and Alamofire

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swifty-json

I want to show data on a Table View. The problem is, I can't get it to show up on it. My code is shown below and I hope somebody can help me out.

```
import Foundation

struct HeroStats {

  let localized_name: String
  let primary_attr: String
  let attack_type: String
  let legs: String
  let img: String
}
```

**Here is my viewController code:**

```
import UIKit
import Alamofire
import SwiftyJSON

class ViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource {

  @IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!
  var heros = [HeroStats]()

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    downloadJson()
    self.tableView.reloadData()


    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self

  }

  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection 
section: Int) -> Int {
    return heros.count
  }

  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: 
IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = UITableViewCell(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: nil)
    cell.textLabel?.text = 
    heros[indexPath.row].localized_name.capitalized
    return cell
  }

  //MARK: Parsing JSON data
  func downloadJson(){
Alamofire.request("https://api.opendota.com/api/heroStats").responseJSON { response in

        if let value = response.result.value {

           let json = JSON(value)

        //Printing strings from a JSON Dictionary
        print(json[0]["localized_name"].stringValue)
        print(json[0]["primary_attr"].stringValue)
        print(json[0]["attack_type"].stringValue)
        print(json[0]["legs"].stringValue)
        print(json[0]["img"].stringValue)
       }
    } // End Alamofire call
  }
}
```

Comment: It appear to be that `heros` was never given any values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The request is `async`. When it gives you a result, you need to parse it and assign it to your array of `HeroStat`. That needs to be done in your request completion handler. You are currently doing **nothing** after you get your response. Also, your call to reloadData is done before you actually get a response, so that won't do.

What you could do is: Once you get your response, populate  the `heros` array and call `tableView.reloadData()` to make it fetch the new populated `HeroStat` values.